# how to add eventsetter by code

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates, event-handling, eventsetter

A complete example

```
    public delegate void mouseup_delegate(object obj, MouseButtonEventArgs args);

    constructor()
    {
        TextBlock text_block = new TextBlock() { Text = "aa" };
        Style style = new Style();
        //style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(){Event=TextBlock.MouseUpEvent, Handler=new mouseup_delegate(this.textblockClicked)});
        style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(TextBlock.MouseUpEvent, new mouseup_delegate(this.textblockClicked)));
        text_block.Style = style;
    }

    public void textblockClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("mouse up");
    }
```

But when I run the app, an exception is thown: Handler type is not valid

what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Does using this instead work? `new EventSetter(TextBlock.MouseUpEvent, new urlClickDelegate(this.url_click))`

Comment: thanks, but the exception still appeared. And if I don't assign url_style(contains the EventSetter) to TextBlock.Style, the exception won't be thrown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EventSetter` expects the delegate you provide to be a `MouseButtonEventHandler`, not a `mouseup_delegate`.

Comment: And what does that look like in C#?